# iexact doesn't work in declaring filterable field in django-filter

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter, django-filters

I am using django-filter lib with DRF.

```py
class OrganizationFilter(FilterSet):

    class Meta:
        model = Organization
        fields = {
            'city': ['iexact', 'contains'],
            'zipcode': ['exact', 'contains']
        }
```

city: CharField

I want to filter city field case-insensitive.

I can make it work by specifying the following.

```
class OrganizationFilter(FilterSet):
    city = filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='iexact')
    ...
```

Unless If I don't specify the lookup_expr it's not working.

I want to know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why, is not working:

```
fields = {
            'city': ['iexact', 'contains'],
            'zipcode': ['exact', 'contains']
        }
```

Is because you specified **'contains'** next to **'iexact'**. **Contains** will perform a case-sensitive lookup which will be in conflict with you're **iexact** lookup. So you're code should look like:

```
class OrganizationFilter(FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Organization
        fields = {
            'city': ['iexact'],
            'zipcode': ['exact', 'contains']
        }
```